# Generate histogram in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012 and need to generate a histogram, conceptually similar to [Google's screener](https://www.google.com/finance#stockscreener)

The idea is to split all the prices into 100 equally sized (based on price) buckets, and then each bucket contains a number of items priced within the bucket's min and max. NTILE didn't work -- it tried to split items equally (based on count) among buckets.

So, this is what I have so far:

```
select bucket, count(*) from (select cast((PERCENT_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Price DESC)) *   100 as int) as bucket  from MyTable
where DataDate = '4/26/2012') t group by bucket
```

Is this a good way to produce a histogram in SQL Server 2012? Is there anything built-in SQL Server 2012 to do this task or a better way?

Thank you

Comment: "*..split all the prices into 100 equally sized (based on price) buckets..*"  To do this you need to determine (or need some rule for determining) what the range of prices to be covered by these 100 buckets will be.

Comment: It's my understanding that PERCENT_RANK gives us a percentage placement of a value in a set. In this case the value is the price and the set is all records on 4/26/2012. Multiplying by 100 and casting to int effectively places each value in one of 100 buckets.

Comment: That just does the same thing as NTILE only in reverse.  IF you want the 100 *price* sub-ranges to be of equal width, then you must start with a range/rule to determine their total width and divide that by 100.  That's simple math.  We need you to decide what that range/rule is.

Answer (score 3):

Like this perhaps:

```
with cte as (
  select base = 1 + u + t*3 from (
    select 0 as u union all select 1 union all select 2
  ) T1
  cross join (
    select 0 as t union all select 1 union all select 2
  ) T2
), data as (
  select * 
  from ( 
   values (1,1,2,3,3,5,7,4,2,1)
  ) data(x0,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9)
)
select cte.base
  ,case when x0>=base then 'X' else  ' ' end as x0
  ,case when x1>=base then 'X' else  ' ' end as x1
  ,case when x2>=base then 'X' else  ' ' end as x2
  ,case when x3>=base then 'X' else  ' ' end as x3
  ,case when x4>=base then 'X' else  ' ' end as x4
  ,case when x5>=base then 'X' else  ' ' end as x5
  ,case when x6>=base then 'X' else  ' ' end as x6
  ,case when x7>=base then 'X' else  ' ' end as x7
  ,case when x8>=base then 'X' else  ' ' end as x8
  ,case when x9>=base then 'X' else  ' ' end as x9
from cte
cross join data
order by base desc
;
```

which yields this histogram nicely:

```
base        x0   x1   x2   x3   x4   x5   x6   x7   x8   x9
----------- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ----
9                                                         
8                                                         
7                                         X               
6                                         X               
5                                    X    X               
4                                    X    X    X          
3                          X    X    X    X    X          
2                     X    X    X    X    X    X    X     
1           X    X    X    X    X    X    X    X    X    X
```

Remember to pivot your data into a single row first.

For a more compact presentation, concatenate the various data columns into a single long string.