# Create range bins from SQL Server table for histograms

Tags: sql, grouping, histogram

I have the following table in SQL Server:

```
-----------------------------
ID       Age          Gender
1          30           F
2          35           M
3          32           M
4          18           F
5          21           F
```

What I need to do is to execute a query that will group the records in given ranges and count the occurences. The results need to be displayed later in a histogram chart (bar chart). I tried a query similar to the following:

```
SELECT 
count(CASE WHEN Age>= 10 AND Age < 20 THEN 1 END) AS '10 - 20',
count(CASE WHEN Age>= 21 AND Age < 30 THEN 1 END) AS '21 - 30',
count(CASE WHEN Age>= 31 AND Age < 35 THEN 1 END) AS '31 - 35',
count(CASE WHEN Age>= 36 AND Age < 40 THEN 1 END) AS '36 - 40',
FROM (SELECT Age FROM Attendees) AS AgeGroups
```

For the moment, this does the trick, but does not consider the gender column. It will result a single row which counts the frequency of every age group:

```
10-20     21-30     31-35     36-40
  0         22        21        13
```

If gender would be considered there should be two records shown, for each gender. I need to see something like:

```
Gender    10-20     21-30     31-35     36-40
  M         0         12        9         6
  F         0         10        12        7
```

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: I demonstrated SQL code to generate a histogram directly here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16268441/generate-histogram-in-sql-server

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Simply add the `Gender` column to your `SELECT` and then do a `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT 
Gender,
count(CASE WHEN Age>= 10 AND Age < 20 THEN 1 END) AS [10 - 20],
count(CASE WHEN Age>= 21 AND Age < 30 THEN 1 END) AS [21 - 30],
count(CASE WHEN Age>= 31 AND Age < 35 THEN 1 END) AS [31 - 35],
count(CASE WHEN Age>= 36 AND Age < 40 THEN 1 END) AS [36 - 40]
FROM Attendees AS AgeGroups
GROUP BY Gender
```

Comment: I believe that you have to use the sum() function instead of the count() function.  Otherwise, each range will equal the total number of records in the Attendees table.  (btw - I have made this same mistake multiple times.)

Comment: @ToddMeinershagen I'm guessing his table has a unique attendee per row as his sample shows, in which case `COUNT` and `SUM` would work the same since `SUM` does not get a value other than 1 for each row

Answer (score 3):

I recently came across a similar problem where I needed to look at several variables rather than just one, and my solution was to use a temporary table.

```
CREATE TABLE #bin (
    startRange int, 
    endRange int,
    agelabel varchar(10)
);
GO

INSERT INTO #bin (startRange, endRange, mylabel) VALUES (10, 20, '10-20')
INSERT INTO #bin (startRange, endRange, mylabel) VALUES (21, 30, '21-30')
INSERT INTO #bin (startRange, endRange, mylabel) VALUES (31, 35, '31-35')
INSERT INTO #bin (startRange, endRange, mylabel) VALUES (36, 40, '36-40')
GO

SELECT 
    b.agelabel as ageBracket, 
    a.Gender, 
    count(a.Gender) as total
FROM 
    Attendees a
INNER JOIN 
    #bin b on (a.Age >= b.startRange and a.Age <= b.EndRange)
GROUP BY
    b.agelabel, a.Gender

DROP TABLE #bin 
GO
```

Or Alternatively, and probably the better solution,

```
With table1 as
(
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN Age >= 10 and Age <= 20 then '10-20'
        WHEN Age > 20 and Age <= 30 then '21-30'
        WHEN Age > 30 and Age <= 35 then '31-35'
        WHEN Age > 35 and Age <= 40 then '36-40'
        ELSE 'NA'
    End as ageBracket,
    Gender
FROM
    Attendees
)

SELECT
    ageBracket,
    Gender,
    Count(Gender),
FROM
    table1
GROUP BY
    ageBracket, Gender
```

Where the result would be :

```
AgeBracket Gender Total
10-20 M 0
10-20 F 0
21-30 M 12
21-30 F 10
31-35 M  9
31-35 F 12
36-40 M  6
36-40 F  7
```

You can use the first select statement to gather all the data of your choice, while using the second query to perform any necessary calculations.

I think these solutions might be a bit overkill for your problem, but as it was the only question I found concerning binning, hopefully it will be useful to others !

Answer (score 2):

The example above excludes values 20, 30, 35, & 40. 
There is more than one way to skin this cat, here is one:

```
SELECT 
Gender,
count(CASE WHEN Age> 9 AND Age <= 20 THEN 1 END) AS [10 - 20],
count(CASE WHEN Age> 20 AND Age <= 30 THEN 1 END) AS [21 - 30],
count(CASE WHEN Age> 30 AND Age <= 35 THEN 1 END) AS [31 - 35],
count(CASE WHEN Age> 35 AND Age <= 40 THEN 1 END) AS [36 - 40]
FROM Attendees AS AgeGroups
GROUP BY Gender
```